# Did someone manage to write application program at a specific offset in PIC18F program memory using MPLAB v.8.92 IDE (C18 compiler)?

Tags: offset, bootloader, mplab, pic18

I've been stuck for a little while now. I am using a PIC18J67j60 with MPLAB IDE (8.92).
My goal is to write my application (application works fine) at the address 0x2A in the PIC18 program memory.
To do so, I added the 18f67j60_g.lkr linker script into my application project (in the "Linker Script" folder). In this 18f67j60_g.lkr script, I added the line : " CODEPAGE  NAME=page  START=0x2A   END=0xFFF".
Then I also added the c018i.c file in the "Source Files" folder of my project and into it, I changed the line "#pragma code _entry_scn=0x000000" to "#pragma code _entry_scn=0x2A".

Everything is compiling and I checked in my project.MAP file and as expected it says : " _entry_scn       code   0x00002a    program   0x000006" and "start 0x00002a   end 0x00013d ".

Then, I use MPLAB IPE only to load the hex.file (obtained from the compilation)  (with a pickit3) into my PIC18 (the picKit3 powers the PIC18). BUT in the output window of MPLAP IPE, it says the start writting address is 0x00.. instead of 0x2A. And I dont get why its not writing at 0x2A address..

Thank you for all your help

Comment: Could you add the first line or so of the hex file to the question so that we can see what address it's referring to?

Comment: Hi thank you for replying,
First line : " :020000040000FA "
Second line : ":06002A0090EF00F012004F"
Third line : " :020030000000CE "
@JoachimIsaksson

Comment: Looks like the (partial) hex file correctly should write 8 bytes starting at address 0x2a. Don't have MPLAB IPE to test with, so can't verify what it actually _does_ write.